# do I need a front end framework in php?

Tags: php

I am new to php, previous Web developments I did was in jsp.

I am about to create a e-commerce site  with basic design. Do I need to use a front-end framework or just do it from scratch? If a framework, what are the best for php  newbies?

Comment: PHP is a server-side language. Whether or not you need a front-end framework is a matter of choice. You don't need it, but it can make things easier (or more difficult, since you would need to learn how to use it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML is the most common front end framework. You should be able to accomplish your goal with a combination of PHP, HTML and javascript. [Here is a list of free PHP ecommerce scripts](http://www.hotscripts.com/category/scripts/php/scripts-programs/e-commerce/shopping-carts/) if you don't feel like coding it all yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks:

1) Html: no framework

2) CSS: Bootstrap

3) Javascript: Jquery

PHP is a server-side language.